# How to avoid stack overflow in deep tree recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, stack-overflow

I've read many similar articles, I apologise if this has already been answered, but I'm still stuck.

I'm coding a function to populate a tree, each node having four branches, which will store the possible manipulation of states of the "eight tile puzzle" i.e.  http://www.8puzzle.com/images/8_puzzle_start_state_a.png

The problem is I've reached, what I believe to be, stack overflow, due to the heavily recursive nature of the problem at hand.

Tail recursion seems like the solution, though I'm not sure if it is relevant/possible or how to implement it in this instance. Code follows:

```
void Tree::insert(string &initialState, const string &goalState, tree_node *&inNode){
cout<<"insert called"<<endl;
depth++;
cout<<depth<<endl;
string modState;
int zeroPos=0;

if(initialState==goalState){
    cout<<"*    *   *   GOAL    *   *   *"<<endl;
    getchar();
    exit(0);
}   

if(inNode==NULL){//is this the first node?

    inNode = new tree_node(initialState);       
    root=inNode;
    inNode->parent=NULL;
    insert(initialState, goalState, inNode);
}else{
    inNode->state = initialState;

    for(zeroPos=0;zeroPos<initialState.size();zeroPos++){//where is the empty tile?
        if(initialState[zeroPos]=='0'){
            break;
        }
    }
    //left
    if(zeroPos!=0 && zeroPos!=3 && zeroPos!=6){//can the empty tile move left?

        modState=initialState;
        modState[zeroPos]=modState[zeroPos-1];
        modState[zeroPos-1]='0';

        if(isOriginal(modState, inNode) ){//does this state already exist?

            cout <<"left  " << modState[0]<<modState[1]<<modState[2]<<endl;
            cout <<"left  " << modState[3]<<modState[4]<<modState[5]<<endl;
            cout <<"left  " << modState[6]<<modState[7]<<modState[8]<<endl;

            inNode->l = new tree_node(modState);    
            inNode->l->parent= inNode;
            if(inNode->l != NULL){
                insert(modState, goalState, inNode->l);
            }
        }
    }

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I haven't gone through your code, but I'd be surprised if you are getting a stack overflow on the 8-puzzle if your algorithm is working properly.

Comment: Perhaps a tree of all states isn't the best possible implementation?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I intended to run various search algorithms, to find steps to the goal state, and record their efficiency in various aspects (time, memory usage etc.).

Comment: @RemnantXO Why are you creating a tree of states _before_ running the search algorithms?

Comment: Hmm. Is there an alternate way to run them? I can't think how to search the states without having them arranged in some structure. Perhaps I'm just being remarkably dimwitted and missing the obvious?

Comment: @RemnantXO In creating the structure you are effectively searching the states, you're just putting them in memory instead of checking for the goal state when you find each one. But the purpose of a good search algorithm is to avoid expanding all the states in the first place.

Comment: I see. But how to "step back", eg. implementing depth first, when you reach the deepest state how do you return to it's predecessor then check it's remaining children without a tree, or tree like, structure?

Comment: @RemnantXO Depth first search is usually written recursively which handles the backtracking - for each unexplored child, call DFS(child) and stop when you get to a goal state. If a state isn't a goal and has no children, return() brings you back to the parent. Other algorithms use different data structures to keep track of which states to visit next, for example breadth first uses a FIFO queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very generic answer, but have you tried to explicitly manage your stack through something like a heap allocated queue or a stack?  Basically don't use actually function calls, just push and pull things off your own stack/queue.  They cover non-recursive graph traversal algorithms [here](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/TDBA36/VT02/lec5.html) (both depth first, and breadth first search).

Answer (score 0):

Optimize your code, meaning only keep those nodes you need. For example only keep leaf nodes (I mean the ones you haven't yet expaneded).
And yes you can search the tree while building it, write a function to measure the distance between your current state and your goal state, its called heuristic. There's also a better algorithm that solves 8puzzle, it's called A*, I suggest you google it.

Comment: Aren't the nodes, being dynamically allocated, stored on the heap though? I will be implementing A* but I'm comparing a range of search functions.

Comment: yes, but you could delete the nodes that you have already expanded that is when you added all it's children, remove the node itself.